# Elections and Probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have such a task. Two candidates participate in the election. The turnout in the elections is 100%. Candidate A got n votes in the elections, and candidate B got m votes. Find the probability that candidate A is always ahead of candidate B by no less than k votes. k, m and n are fixed.

I think this way: If candidate A always has at least k more votes than candidate B, then the first moves have already been identified. Candidate A has k votes, candidate B has 0 votes, it remains to distribute n+m-k votes. The next (k+1) vote will be received by candidate A, because if B received it, the condition that A is always ahead of candidate B by no less than k votes will be break.

Now the part that I do not understand has begun. Please tell me how to solve the problem further. Thanks for Your attention! Hope You can help me.

Comment: You've reduced it to [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: @saulspatz Thank You! Now I understand how to solve it)

Comment: Glad to be of help.